# How to pluralize the word Legacy?

Tags: plural-forms, conjugations

I try to find out how to pluralize the word [Legacy](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy).
Like:
one Legacy
two Legacies
three Legacies

Is this correct?
I search online but all I can find is what the word "plural" means not a way to pluralize

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/legacy?s=t

Comment: I agree with and have upvoted David Hall's answer, but just so you know, there are cases where legacy could be "legacys." I wouldn't say it's grammatically-correct, but I would say it's fitting (e.g., http://digitallegacys.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plural form is **"Legacies"** as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legacy) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legacies) state.